# Can I define 'nights and days' in the sentence as an approximate time period?

Tags: usage

If so, how many nights and days approximately? Does it depend on the context?

> Our success has been the product of sleepless ***nights*** and
> ***days*** of hard work.

Answer (score 5):

No. In that sentence, "nights and days" is not a constituent phrase on its own. The phrase "sleepless nights and days of hard work" is a compound noun phrase describing the two things that produced the success.

It's not a time period. It's roughly equivalent to:

> Our success has been the product of not sleeping at night, and working hard during the day.

No indication of a time span there.

Comment: If you wanted to indicate a time, you'd say something like "many sleepless days and nights" or "years of sleepless days and nights". As it stands, it's just a description of the nights and days.